# Лабораторная. Не вычисляет значение функции

Tags: c++, функции

Написал лабораторную, но при вводе значений x,y,z, выводится значение 0.
Помогите найти причину и исправить ее

[image: Скрин вывода]
[image: Значения для теста]

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <math.h>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    double f1(double x); //F3
    double f2(double x); // G5
    double f3(double x); // H9
    double f4(double x); // F5
    int main()

    {
        double x, y, z, R;

        cout << "x = ";
        cin >> x;

        cout << "y = ";
        cin >> y;

        cout << "z = ";
        cin >> z;


        R = f1(x) - f2(f3(y)) + f4(z);
        cout <<"R = " << R << endl;
        system("pause");
    }

    double f1(double x)
    {
        double f = 0;
        f = (((2 * 3 + 1) / 3 * 3)*f - (3 / 4)*x*f);
        return f;
    }

    double f2(double x)
    {
        double f = 0;
        f = 2 * (x*x)*f + (5 / 7)*f;
        return f;
    }

    double f3(double x)
    {
        double f = 0 ;
        f = 2 * x*x - 9 * (x*x)*x;
        return f;
    }

    double f4(double x)
    {
        double f = 0;
        f = ((2 * 5 + 1) / 5 * 5)*f - (5 / 6)*x*f;
        return f;
    }
```

Comment: зачем описывать в функции то, что можно явно посчитать на калькуляторе типа(5+2/3)*f, можно записать как 5.66*f т. о. можно записать f1 как:
f = 0.77778*f - 0.75*x*f а если приравнять к нулю, получится:
-f * (0.75 * x - 0.233333) = 0
в общем сначала можно привести формулы в более простой вид

Comment: Пожалуйста, удалите Ваш ответ, т.к. он является не ответом, а комментарием. Когда Вы заработаете 50 баллов репутации, Вы сможете оставлять комментарии к вопросом

Comment: зачем писать длинную формулу (5+4+8+65/5-4)*x=f, если можно написать f = 26*x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уж сколько раз твердили миру...

Кроме того, что вам уже ответил [Andrej Levkovitch](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/261597/andrej-levkovitch) про непонятное умножение на 0, еще учтите и такое - не используйте целочисленное деление там, где оно не нужно! Ваше какое-нибудь

```
5/6
```

дает 0, как это ни удивительно может вам показаться. Вот, посмотрите сами - https://ideone.com/UpVcbG

Так что не используйте целочисленную арифметику там, где она не нужна. Запишите коэффициенты в вычислениях как числа с плавающей точкой (можно не все, но пока вы не разберетесь основательно - лучше добавляйте точки ко всему...).

Answer (score 1):

Ну так все правильно: у вас только функция `f3` будет возвращать не нулевое значение. У вас ведь в каждой функции происходит умножение на 0 при вычислении результирующего значения (кроме `f3`). Проверьте правильность формул (почему у вас происходит умножение на `f`, которое вы инициализировали нулем?). И посмотрите также, что писал Harry - преобразование типов тоже причина вывода нулевых значений.